# check if url is to HTML in R

Tags: html, r, url

What is the best way to check if url is to HTML site in R?

Currently I use:

```
x <- "http://google.com/
fileUrl <- (x)     
htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal=T)
```

This will return error, if URL is not HTML. However, I was wondering if there more proper way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `HEAD` from the `httr` package to inspect the `Content-Type` the server says it will return:

```
library(httr)
resp <- HEAD("http://google.com/")
resp$headers$`content-type`
## [1] "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
```